# Leaving Switzerland during studies, EU citizen

Tags: accommodation, covid-19, switzerland, study

I'm an EU citizen, and study in Zurich, Switzerland. I'm enrolled for the following semester.

My housing lease is expiring and I haven't managed to find other affordable accommodation, so I must leave Switzerland for my home country. My residence permit expires on the same day as my lease, and I've applied for an extension before I knew I would not find accommodation.

1. What will happen to my residence permit, which is being processed right now? Will I be able to enter Switzerland again when I find some apartment? (If e.g. my country is on a high-risk Covid19 list then.)
2. Am I breaking some Swiss law if I receive my residence permit, but don't have an address for some time? Is my residence permit valid for entering Switzerland again?
3. Is it a good idea to pay someone that I know to register me as a subtenant, so I have a postal address? I don't plan on being in Switzerland for a while, I will only maybe need to reenter for exams. Is this even legal?

Comment: I find "expatriate" a strange term, as I would never call myself something like that. This is what a Swiss person coming to live at my country would be called, but not vice versa.

I'm a student, and after that I can maybe be an immigrant, but never an expatriate. 

But thanks anyways, I will double-post there.

Comment: I don't know how that SE site came to be with that domain. I didn't post there because of the title, but it seems like it's actually a mixture of immigration and expatriate questions.

Comment: I fail to understand why a Swiss person coming to live in your country could be an expatriate but not vice-versa. Anybody living (as opposed to travelling) in a country other than their own is an expat, by definition.